# why i cannot access my website with its ipaddress. but only with sitename. Is this common?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have website http://waycoolblog.com, but I cannot access it through its ip address
http://74.220.219.56/

Why is this happening?

My main question is whether this is a common thing. In my app I am trying to the resolve the sitename myself and trying to connect with the ip-address instead of sitename.

I want to make sure this that works properly.

Comment: It will work fine, but you will have to send the header `Hostname: waycoolblog.com` as part of your HTTP request.

Comment: @Martin - oops, you're right of course! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6):

Not knowing the server on which you are running, but in IIS, there is the host-header mapping function.

This allows multiple websites to run from the same IP address, but requires that the domain name of the web site is supplied as the "Host" http request header. The server queries this header and serves the content from the appropriate site.

Any request coming in via the IP address will not have "waycoolblog.com" as the host header. If your server is hosting more than one web site, chances are that yours is not the 'default', so the server won't serve your site.

Comment: Based on the default site for the IP and a reverse DNS lookup, it looks like the server is used for shared hosting. This behaviour is normal for cheap hosting.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the server your site is on is using [hostname-based VirtualHosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Host*name*-based virtual hosting is extremely common. Without it, the shortage of IP addresses would be much more serious. How it works? The HTTP/1.1 client passes a `Host` header as part of its request that says which host was of interest (`waycoolblog.com` in your case) and the HTTP server works out which set of content to serve up based off that. That enables the same IP address to serve many different hostnames' content, keeping hosting much cheaper. It's also a feature of every production-grade standard web server software system. Apache does it, as does IIS and every other one I know about that isn't a research toy.

The fix for you is to pass the `Host` header correctly in the client code that is making the connection. Then everything should Just Work<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: Is there any other case which i need to handle when i try to access the website using the ip-address?
Does that work always when that host header is passed in the request?

Comment: @railscoder: It depends on your client library, really. As long as the `Host` header is set, you'll be fine, but that's usually done by the client library for you based off the URL you passed in for it to fetch (because that's the Right Thing). IIRC, things can be more complex with HTTPS-based fetches, but I don't know the exact nuances there.